# How to set maxmemoryconsumptionperiterator during delete operation in KQL?

Tags: kql, azure-data-explorer

I'm trying to dedupe data for a given day in Kusto (I know materialized views are preferred but for this use case I need to use a query). I tried the following query:

```
.delete table TABLE records with (whatif=true) <| 
    TABLE
    | where Timestamp < ago(0d) and Timestamp > ago(1d)
    | sort by Key, ingestion_time() desc
    | where row_cumsum(1,prev(Key) != Key) > 1
```

but this gives me runaway query errors due to memory budget of 8gb being hit. I tried setting it to 64gb, but including it either outside the .delete or inside the .delete didn't work:

```
set maxmemoryconsumptionperiterator=68719476736;

.delete table TABLE records with (whatif=true) <| 
    TABLE
    | where Timestamp < ago(0d) and Timestamp > ago(1d)
    | sort by Key, ingestion_time() desc
    | where row_cumsum(1,prev(Key) != Key) > 1

or

.delete table TABLE records with (whatif=true) <| 
    set maxmemoryconsumptionperiterator=68719476736;
    TABLE
    | where Timestamp < ago(0d) and Timestamp > ago(1d)
    | sort by Key, ingestion_time() desc
    | where row_cumsum(1,prev(Key) != Key) > 1
```

Both of those fail with some error either about incomplete fragment or missing }. Is there something I'm missing here syntax-wise, or is this just not possible for .delete and other . commands? I'd like to avoid increasing resources on the cluster if possible.